# How list_iterator is sub-class of Iterator even though MROs are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code. From the output the MROs are different but still `issubclass` returns true. Can someone explain how Python finds they are equal?

My understanding is that MRO show the inheritance tree of classes. And classes with different inheritance tree (MRO) should not satisfy sub-class validation. I am using Python-3.9.5 on Windows-10

**Code**

```
from collections.abc import Iterator

it_type = type(iter([]))
print(it_type.__mro__)
print(Iterator.__mro__)
print(issubclass(it_type, Iterator))
```

**Output**

```
(<class 'list_iterator'>, <class 'object'>)
(<class 'collections.abc.Iterator'>, <class 'collections.abc.Iterable'>, <class 'object'>)
True
```

Comment: Presumably you mean that `collections.abc.Iterator` is not present in `list_iterator`'s MRO, not merely that the MROs are different (all classes *must* have different MROs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass) for the `issubclass` function (emphasis mine):

> Return `True` if class is a subclass (direct, indirect, **or virtual**) of `classinfo`.

Following the link to the definition of a [virtual subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class):

> ABCs introduce virtual subclasses, which are classes that don’t inherit from a class but are still recognized by `isinstance()` and `issubclass()`; see the abc module documentation.

Following that link to the [`abc` module documentation](https://An%20ABC%20can%20be%20subclassed%20directly,%20and%20then%20acts%20as%20a%20mix-in%20class.%20You%20can%20also%20register%20unrelated%20concrete%20classes%20(even%20built-in%20classes)%20and%20unrelated%20ABCs%20as%20%E2%80%9Cvirtual%20subclasses%E2%80%9D%20%E2%80%93%20these%20and%20their%20descendants%20will%20be%20considered%20subclasses%20of%20the%20registering%20ABC%20by%20the%20built-in%20issubclass()%20function,%20but%20the%20registering%20ABC%20won%E2%80%99t%20show%20up%20in%20their%20MRO%20(Method%20Resolution%20Order)):

> An ABC can be subclassed directly, and then acts as a mix-in class. You can also register unrelated concrete classes (even built-in classes) and unrelated ABCs as “virtual subclasses” – these and their descendants will be considered subclasses of the registering ABC by the built-in `issubclass()` function, but the registering ABC won’t show up in their MRO (Method Resolution Order)

Comment: Is there any method to show the registered sub-classes?

Comment: @Dinesh It doesn't seem like it; there is a class attribute `Iterable._abc_cache` which holds a list of classes which are registered as virtual subclasses, but classes only appear here after checking them with `issubclass` as far as I can tell. So virtual subclasses are probably registered lazily, and you can't get a list of all of them without knowing in advance that they have all already registered themselves.